# Actions on the same apache Spark RDD cause all statements re-execution

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am using Apache Spark to process a huge amount of data. I need to execute many Spark actions on the same `RDD`. My code looks like the following:

```
val rdd = /* Get the rdd using the SparkContext */
val map1 = rdd.map(/* Some transformation */)
val map2 = map1.map(/* Some other transformation */)
map2.count
val map3 = map2.map(/* More transformation */)
map3.count
```

The problem is that calling the second action `map3.count` forces the re-execution of the transformations `rdd.map` and `map1.map`.

What the hell is going on? I think the *DAG* built by Spark is responible of this behaviour.

Comment: Do you have a minimal working example to reproduce that behavior? I tried something obvious with `println` in `map` to show which operation is being performed, but when I call `collect` on the second one, I only get the second, not the first also.

Comment: I have corrected my question, that was not so accurate. Tomorrow I will be able to give a working example. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an expected behavior. Unless one of the ancestor can be fetched from cache (typically it means that is has been persisted explicitly or implicitly during shuffle) every action will recompute a whole lineage.

Recomputation can be also triggered if RDD has been persisted but data has been lost / removed from cache or amount of available space is to low to store all records.

In this particular case you should `cache` in a following order

```
...
val map2 = map1.map(/* Some other transformation */)
map2.cache
map2.count
val map3 = map2.map(/* More transformation */)
...
```

if you want to avoid repeated evaluation of `rdd`, `map1` and `map2`.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with my spark job, but in my case data is huge so caching is probably not possible. Is there any other option so that I can avoid data reshuffling. Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Atul Shuffled data will reuse shuffle files. See [What does “Stage Skipped” mean in Apache Spark web UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34580662/1560062) and other questions which are linked to it. Also caching with memory and disk should be possible in general.