# Understanding Spark DAG Execution

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I'd like to understand Spark DAG model according to the [official Spark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html). All transformations in Spark are lazy and by default, each transformed RDD may be recomputed each time you run an action on it. So I wrote a small program like below:

```
scala> val lines = sc.textFile("C:\\Spark\\README.md")
lines: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = C:\Spark\README.md MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:24

scala> val breakLInes = lines.flatMap(line=>line.split(" "))
breakLInes: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[2] at flatMap at <console>:26

scala> val createTuple = breakLInes.map(line=>(line,1))
createTuple: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at <console>:28

scala> val wordCount = createTuple.reduceByKey
reduceByKey   reduceByKeyLocally

scala> val wordCount = createTuple.reduceByKey(_+_)
wordCount: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ShuffledRDD[4] at reduceByKey at <console>:30

scala> wordCount.first
res0: (String, Int) = (package,1)
```

Now moving to spark UI below is my DAG Visualization for the first action:

[image]

Again executed:

```
scala> wordCount.first
res0: (String, Int) = (package,1)
```

Now moving to spark UI below is my DAG Visualization for the second action:

[image]

By default, each transformed RDD may be recomputed each time you run an action on it. Then why it is skipping stage 2 it should have again calculated stage 2 as no caching has been done?

Comment: Spark automatically stores shuffle files and can load them as if you had called persist explicitly.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34580662/what-does-stage-skipped-mean-in-apache-spark-web-ui