# Apache Spark: Dag is not executed twice for reduceByKey

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, directed-acyclic-graphs

Have a simple, maybe weird question: for the following code DAG is executed twice which is expected, because I'm calling action two times:

```scala
val input = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4))
val result = input.map(x => {
  println("!!! Input Map !!!")
  errorLines.add(1)
  (x,1)
})
//.reduceByKey(_+_)
println(result.count())
println(result.collect())
```

If I uncomment `reduceByKey` line - DAG will be executed only once, although `reduceByKey` is transformation and I'm calling actions two times.

Does that mean that Spark just doesn't always recompute DAG?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shuffle files in Spark serve as an implicit cache, so whenever your pipeline contains a shuffle stage (like `*ByKey`), and there is node failure involved, Spark will repeat only the last stage.

That being said neither using stdout, nor accumulators `errorLines` is a one) in transformations is reliable. During normal execution, the former one will lost, and the latter one doesn't provide exactly once guarantees.

Related to [What does "Stage Skipped" mean in Apache Spark web UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34580662/1560062)