# cache or not cache in groupByKey

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark, caching

currently having a discussion with a colleague about how caching whould benefit in the following scenario:

```
  val dataset1 = sparkSession.read.json("...") // very expensive read
  val dataset2 = sparkSession.read.json("...") // very expensive read

  val joinedDataset = dataset1.join(dataset2)

  val reducedDataset = joinedDataset
    .mapPartitions {
      ???
    }
    .groupByKey("key")
    .reduceGroups {
      ???
    }

  reducedDataset.write.json("...")
```

would it help (if yes please explain why) caching the *joinedDataset* to increase the performance of the *reduce* operation?

it would be:

```
  val dataset1 = sparkSession.read.json("...") // very expensive read
  val dataset2 = sparkSession.read.json("...") // very expensive read

  val joinedDataset = dataset1.join(dataset2).cache

  val reducedDataset = joinedDataset
    .mapPartitions {
      ???
    }
    .groupByKey("key")
    .reduceGroups {
      ???
    }

  reducedDataset.write.json("...")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be benchmark it but it'll either won't have effect at all or even degrade performance:

- No effect at all because `cached` data is not reused. Even it was reused, join would be a barrier of recomputation.
- Might degrade performance because caching in general is expensive.

Comment: thank you. even if the reduce operation is applied on a non joined data i.e. dataset1, no recomputation is needed for the reduce operation right?

Comment: Yes, all computations are pipelined and there is no branching here. Also see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/34580662/8371915