# First stage of action in Spark ran by only one executor

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I have a spark program running with YARN as master and in client mode with 3 executors
By reading data from ElasticSearch through a connector i'm able to load them into a dataframe.
Such dataframe is repartitioned using `df = df.repartition(3)` in three partitions.
Whenever i try to do an action such as `count()` or `show()` for example, the first stage, which from this thread: [Why spark count action has executed in three stages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730826/why-spark-count-action-has-executed-in-three-stages) i understood it's about reading the file, has only one task and it's ran by a single executor.
Is this behavior expected for this stage? shouldn't i be able to run this stage in parallel with all the executor allocated?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the replication of your data.
If your data is replicated on more Data Nodes, you potentially have more executors that are able to read from.

Comment: Could you go more in detail since i'm new to spark. I'm running YARN on a single node in pseudo distributed mode with one Datanode, however multiple executors should be able to read from the data with `repartition()` right? even if  it's a single datanode.