# Spark - Stage 0 running with only 1 Executor

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have docker containers running Spark cluster - 1 master node and 3 workers registered to it. The worker nodes have 4 cores and 2G.
Through the pyspark shell in the master node, I am writing a sample program to read the contents of an RDBMS table into a DataFrame. Further I am doing df.repartition(24). Then I am doing df.write to another RDMBS table (in a different database server). The df.write starts the DAG execution. I can see from the executors page that only one executor is active with a task for Stage 0. Should the write not happen from all executors in parallel? I checked to ensure that all partitions had evenly distributed records.

A similar question was asked earlier- but is not answered satisfactorily.
[First stage of action in Spark ran by only one executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65087523/first-stage-of-action-in-spark-ran-by-only-one-executor)

Sample code -

```
df= spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:hostname:port:database") \
    .option("query", source_query) \
    .option("user", user) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
    .load()
df=df.repartition(24)
df.write \
        .format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/" + destination) \
        .option("dbtable", destination + '.'+target) \
        .option("user", user) \
        .option("password", password) \
        .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") \
        .mode("append") \
        .save()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out.
In the first stage of reading data from the JDBC source, only one executor is active because by default, Spark tries to read data from a JDBC source using a single task, which is executed by a single executor. This is done to minimize the overhead associated with creating and managing multiple connections to the database.

To increase the parallelism while reading data from a JDBC source, you can use the partitionColumn and lowerBound and upperBound options. By specifying these options, Spark can read data from the source in parallel across multiple tasks and executors. When using these options, Spark will partition the data based on the values of the partitioning column and create multiple tasks, each of which reads a separate partition of the data.

Updated Code-

```
df= spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:hostname:port:database") \
    .option("dbtable", source_query) \
    .option("user", user) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
    .option("partitionColumn", "row_num") \
    .option("lowerBound", "1") \
    .option("upperBound", "450000") \
    .option("numPartitions", "24") \
    .load()
```

Now I can see all executors in action for Stage 0