# why an action takes multiple jobs to get completed in spark - scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am doing a pivot operation on top of a dataframe in spark-scala. But for the single pivot it is taking multiple jobs to get completed(as per the pic below)

What could be the possible reason?

[image]

This is rather a generic question as I experience the same in other actions well.

Comment: can you show the code pls? where the pivot is concerned

Comment: I have lot of underlying joins in the code

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, `pivot` causes Spark to launch underwater jobs for the pivot values to be pivoted. You can supply them to obviate afaik, but that is not generally done.

`show` and `reading s3 paths` also cause Spark to generate extra Jobs, also `take`, as well `schema inference by` Spark.

Most of the blurb on Actions and Jobs is from RDDs. With DF's and Catalysts things like optimization mean things can be initiated so as to improved performance.

Also, the display on Spark UI is hard for many to follow. Often the name of the Job remains the same, but it concerns the work done for `wide-transformations` involving `shuffling` known as `Stages`. `groupBy, orderBy, agg` all do their thing based on "shuffle boundaries". It's the way it works. Your code shows those things.

This [Spark: disk I/O on stage boundaries explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58699907/spark-disk-i-o-on-stage-boundaries-explanation/58841524#58841524) may give some insight as well as to what is going on in the background. The output of a grouBy is input to an orderBy over two Stages.

Comment: This is rather  generic question. This happens for insertinto.count etc

Comment: The answer is still valid here as we can see pivot in Spark UI.

Comment: Could you please explain your answer ?

Comment: You need to show the code, but pivot must get a list of pivot values so as to perform the pivoting subsequently

Comment: var df31_in = df.withColumn("c1", max("c2") over Window.partitionBy("x")
 ).groupBy("x","c1").pivot("RANK_NUM").agg(first("x2")
 ).withColumnRenamed("c1", "c2")

Comment: My code is something like this. I have some series of joins prior attaining this intial df

Comment: Updated, I find the Spark UI hard to follow at times.

Comment: ok, Let me try to understand this, as this seems lil bit complicated for me :)