# Why does spark shuffle when it is going to use broadcast while using Adaptive Query Execution

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I was going through the Spark SQL for a join optimised using Adaptive Query Execution,

On the right side, spark get to know the size of table is small enough for broadcast and therefore decides for broadcast hash join.

As we know, broadcast hash join in a narrow operation, why do we still have exchange in the left table (large one)

[image: Spark SQL]

Even in the final Physical plan, exchange is there

[image: Physical Plan]

https://www.databricks.training/spark-ui-simulator/experiment-3799A/v002-S/index.html?artifact=sql-21

Answer (score 1):

You get a *local* shuffle based on Mappers, not Reducers. I.e. a *localized* shuffle instead of *regular* such shuffle.

See https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/what-new-apache-spark-3-local-shuffle-reader/read and https://dev.to/yaooqinn/how-to-use-spark-adaptive-query-execution-aqe-in-kyuubi-2ek2

For background you can also peruse [Spark: disk I/O on stage boundaries explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58699907/spark-disk-i-o-on-stage-boundaries-explanation)