How operation shuffle works in spark?
In Apache Spark, shuffle operations involve transferring data between executors to redistribute data based on keys.
As per my understanding, this process shuffles involves several steps:
Serialization: Data is serialized into a format suitable for transmission.
Writing to Disk: The serialized data is written as shuffle files to disk on the sender executor.
Data Transfer: The shuffle files are then sent over the network to the recipient executors.
I have a question about this:
Why does Spark write shuffle files to disk after serialization instead of sending them directly to other executors?

Look here and mark up pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58699907/spark-disk-i-o-on-stage-boundaries-explanation/58841524#58841524
