# pyspark skipped some import stage, this stage should handle new data and should not be skipped

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

my core pyspark code in a forloop.

```
global_v = np.random.rand(feature_num, vec_dim)
global_v_bc = sc.broadcast(global_v)
for i in range(epoch):
    s1 = train_rdd.repartition(500)\
            .mapPartitions(lambda x:fit(x, global_v_bc))\
            .reduceByKey(lambda x,y:[x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1], x[2]+y[2]])\
            .map(lambda x:x[1])
    s2 = s1.take(1)[0]
    s1.unpersist()
    logging.info("epoch {} train-loss:{}".format(i, s2[0]/s2[1]))
    global_v_bc.destroy()
    global_v_bc = sc.broadcast(s2[2]/s2[1])
```

It is a simple fm model. It is can update v in each partition and re-broadcast it for the next loop, but many stage are skipped wheh it runs.

can someone help me~

here is the web UI content:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Stage Skipped" mean in Apache Spark web UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34580662/what-does-stage-skipped-mean-in-apache-spark-web-ui)

Comment: @cronoik ,I have repartition the data, update the broadcast value and unpersist the cached rdd, so I think the stage should not be skipped.

Comment: Have you debugged to check that your global variable is NOT being updated? What are the tasks being skipped? It could be that its just skipping the initial s1 call to train_rdd. So forming train_rdd is done once and then every other time its skipped since its constant....