# How to improve write to synapse in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-synapse

I have a script to do **write** a dataframe to synapse, the flow of my script is `Read from Synapse > Transform data on Databricks (GROUP BY CUBE) > Write to Synapse`, the data that I read from synapse has 150 million row **(Fact Table)**, I do `GROUP BY CUBE` to transform the fact table. Now, I have a problem here, the process from **write** so slowly, I still didn't know what's the problem here.

I have tried some solution:

```
- Auto optimize
%sql set spark.databricks.delta.properties.defaults.autoOptimize.optimizeWrite = true;
set spark.databricks.delta.properties.defaults.autoOptimize.autoCompact = true;

- Repartition
df.repartition(10000)

- Adaptive Query Execution (AQE)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.optimizeSkewedJoin.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", "true")

- Write Semantics
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.sqldw.writeSemantics", "copy")
```

Nothing from them solved my problem, and it still write slowly.

This is my **time process**. , as you can see, some of the job skipped, why does it happen?

[image]

This is my **specification**:

[image]

This is my **read** from synapse script:

```py
df = (spark.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")
    .option("url", url)
    .option("tempDir", tempDir)
    .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true")
    .option("query", sql)
    .load()
)
```

This is my **write** to synapse script:

```py
df.write
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")
  .option("tableOptions", "CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX, DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN") # Added at 20200121
  .option("url", url)
  .option("dbtable", table)
  .option("forward_spark_azure_storage_credentials","True")
  .option("tempdir", tempDir)
  .mode(write_mode)
  .save()
```

This is my **transform** script:

```
cube_department_read = cube_department_df.cube(cube_department_df["YEAR"], cube_department_df["WeekOfYear"], cube_department_df["Month"], 
                                cube_department_df["department_groups"], cube_department_df["category_name"], 
                                cube_department_df["subcategory_name"], cube_department_df["section_name"]) \
        .agg(F.max('last_date_of_week').alias('last_date_of_week'), 
             F.countDistinct('internal_tranx_key').alias('sales_basket'), 
             F.sum('SalesAmt').alias('sales_amt'), 
             F.sum('SalesQty').alias('sales_qty'),
             F.sum('SalesQtyPro').alias('SalesQtyPro'), 
             F.sum('SalesAmtPro').alias('SalesAmtPro'),
             F.countDistinct('membership_id').alias('member_count'),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull(), 
                        cube_department_df["SalesQty"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesQty_Member"),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull(), 
                        cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesAmt_Member"),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull(), 
                        1).otherwise(0)).alias("Basket_Count_Member"),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull(), 
                        0).otherwise(cube_department_df["SalesQty"])).alias("SalesQty_NonMember"),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull(), 
                        0).otherwise(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"])).alias("SalesAmt_NonMember"),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull(), 
                        0).otherwise(1)).alias("Basket_Count_NonMember"),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y', 
                        cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesAmt_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y', 
                        cube_department_df["SalesQty"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesQty_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y', 
                        1).otherwise(0)).alias("Basket_Count_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y', 
                        0).otherwise(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"])).alias("SalesAmt_Non_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y', 
                        0).otherwise(cube_department_df["SalesQty"])).alias("SalesQty_Non_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when(cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y', 
                        0).otherwise(1)).alias("Basket_Count_Non_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull()), 
                        cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesAmt_Member_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull()), 
                        cube_department_df["SalesQty"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesQty_Member_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull()), 
                        1).otherwise(0)).alias("Basket_Count_Member_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNull()), 
                        cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesAmt_Non_Member_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNull()), 
                        cube_department_df["SalesQty"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesQty_Non_Member_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'Y') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNull()), 
                        1).otherwise(0)).alias("Basket_Count_Non_Member_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'N') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull()), 
                        cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesAmt_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'N') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull()), 
                        cube_department_df["SalesQty"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesQty_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'N') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNotNull()), 
                        1).otherwise(0)).alias("Basket_Count_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'N') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNull()), 
                        cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesAmt_Non_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'N') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNull()), 
                        cube_department_df["SalesQty"]).otherwise(0)).alias("SalesQty_Non_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion"),
             F.sum(F.when((cube_department_df["promotion_flag"] == 'N') & (cube_department_df["membership_id"].isNull()), 
                        1).otherwise(0)).alias("Basket_Count_Non_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion"),
            F.when((F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesQty"]) < 0) & (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) < 0),
                (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) / F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesQty"])) * -1) \
                .when((F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesQty"]) == 0) | (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) == 0),
                0).otherwise(F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) / F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesQty"])).alias("sales_per_unit"),
            F.when((F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesQty"]) < 0) & (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) < 0),
                (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) / F.countDistinct(cube_department_df["internal_tranx_key"])) * -1) \
                .when((F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesQty"]) == 0) | (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) == 0),
                0).otherwise(F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) / F.countDistinct(cube_department_df["internal_tranx_key"])).alias("sales_per_basket"),
            F.when((F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesQty"]) < 0) & (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) < 0),
                (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesQty"]) / F.countDistinct(cube_department_df["internal_tranx_key"])) * -1) \
                .when((F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesQty"]) == 0) | (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) == 0),
                0).otherwise(F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesQty"]) / F.countDistinct(cube_department_df["internal_tranx_key"])).alias("unit_per_basket"),    
            F.when((F.countDistinct(cube_department_df["membership_id"]) < 0) & (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) < 0),
                (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) / F.countDistinct(cube_department_df["membership_id"])) * -1) \
                .when((F.countDistinct(cube_department_df["membership_id"]) == 0) | (F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) == 0),
                0).otherwise(F.sum(cube_department_df["SalesAmt"]) / F.countDistinct(cube_department_df["membership_id"])).alias("spend_per_customer")) \
        .select("YEAR","WeekOfYear","Month","department_groups","category_name","subcategory_name","section_name",
                "last_date_of_week","sales_basket","sales_amt","sales_qty","SalesQtyPro","SalesAmtPro",
                "member_count","SalesQty_Member","SalesAmt_Member", "Basket_Count_Member",
                "SalesQty_NonMember","SalesAmt_NonMember", "Basket_Count_NonMember", 
                "SalesAmt_MMDS_Promotion", "SalesQty_MMDS_Promotion", "Basket_Count_MMDS_Promotion",
                "SalesAmt_Non_MMDS_Promotion","SalesQty_Non_MMDS_Promotion", "Basket_Count_Non_MMDS_Promotion",
                "SalesAmt_Member_MMDS_Promotion","SalesQty_Member_MMDS_Promotion","Basket_Count_Member_MMDS_Promotion",
                "SalesAmt_Non_Member_MMDS_Promotion","SalesQty_Non_Member_MMDS_Promotion","Basket_Count_Non_Member_MMDS_Promotion",
                "SalesAmt_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion","SalesQty_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion","Basket_Count_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion",
               "SalesAmt_Non_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion","SalesQty_Non_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion","Basket_Count_Non_Member_Non_MMDS_Promotion",
                "sales_per_unit","sales_per_basket","unit_per_basket", "spend_per_customer") \
        .orderBy(F.col("YEAR").asc(), 
           F.col("WeekOfYear").asc(), 
           F.col("Month").asc(),
           F.col("department_groups").asc(), 
           F.col("category_name").asc(),
           F.col("subcategory_name").asc(), 
           F.col("section_name").asc())
```

Comment: do you really need that `orderBy` at the end? because `orderBy` is not an efficient operation as it sorts data across partitions

Comment: I had removed that, but still not working, still slow